# cplex callbacks: getting the branching variable

Tags: cplex, callback

I would like to obtain the number of the variable cplex branches on at the current node during B&B.

I try this by using the callback

```
status = CPXXgetcallbacknodeinfo (env,cbdata,wherefrom,0,CPX_CALLBACK_INFO_NODE_VAR, &bvar) ;
```

bvar is supposed to hold the id of the branching variable. The statement fails as the returned value of bvar is not the correct one.

Could anyone indicate what I am doing wrong?  For experimenting, I am using the code of the CPLEX example xadmipex1.c